# Calendar uncheck checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement checkboxes in order to select days. I can add the event when the checkbox is selected using `ng-click="addEvent()"`. However, when it gets clicked again, the `ng-click` runs again, adding the same event again.

How can I make it so when the checkbox is uncheck, that it removes event from calendar?

Here is my code:

```
<label ng-repeat="day in days"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="days" checklist-value="day" ng-click="addEvent(day, exercise)">{{ day.text }} </label>
```

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem (or at least add code to your question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery try this:

```
$( 'input' ).change(function() {
 if($( 'input' ).prop( 'checked' )) {
  addEvent();
 }
}
```

Although you should give a `id` to the input. Then just use (when id is "input-1") `$(#input-1).prop('checked')` inside the if statement condition